# receiving symbols from udp, why ?

Tags: python, network-programming, udp

I have written a listen python udp code to receive a stream which the output should numbers of 1 to 42, however, the output seems to be 42 symbols instead of values(as such):

1450472711.51 :        @      4@     @P@      $@      @      @      @      @       @      "@      $@      &@      (@      *@      ,@      .@      0@      1@      2@      3@      4@      5@      6@      7@      8@      9@      :@      ;@      <@      =@      >@      ?@      @@     �@@      A@     �A@      B@     �B@      C@     �C@      D@     �D@

Here is the code: I sniffed the packets and they seems to all be 378 packets long and this continues to happen, so i dont see any packet drop.

```
import socket,sys, ast , os
from time import ctime
import time
print >> sys.stderr, os.getcwd()
print >> sys.stderr ,  ctime()



sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
ip = '192.168.10.101'
port = 25000
server_address = (ip, port)

sock.bind(server_address)   # bind socket

sock.settimeout(2)          # sock configuration
sock.setblocking(1)
print >> sys.stderr, 'able to bind'
i = 0
client = ''

byte = 378
while True:
    if i == 0:
        print >> sys.stderr, 'connected'
    data,client = sock.recvfrom(byte)
    print >> sys.stderr,time.time() ,":",data , "\n"
    i= i+1
```

Anyone able to explain why this is? is there some conversion I am not doing when the packets are received ?

thank you !

Comment: How is the data encoded? We have to see what the server does.

Comment: I wish I knew how to respond to that question. The messages being sent is from a microzed FPGA by Xilinx coded by simulink which has its own UDP send block but mentions nothing about encoding. If I do find out, ill post it up. unless anyone happens to know how that is encoded. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing a string of binary data.  To see the actual binary (bytewise) numbers that are transmitted, try something like:

```
for c in data:
    print ord(c)
```

Comment: Hi, I now receive 336 values which this is the value of the size of the data packet when i look in wireshark. How do i convert these to give the oiriginal input values which are numbers 1 to 43 that  are multiplexed and sent by tht udp block in simulink. Here are some of the 336 values(as much as I could paste here) : 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
8
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
16
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
20
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
24
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
28
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
32
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
34
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
36
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
38
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
40
64
0
0
0
0
0
0
42
64
0
0

Comment: Those values look like "long long"s, that is, 8 byte numbers.  And, as you originally said you send 42 of the, 42 * 8 = 336, which makes sense.  However, the 8 bytes values are not 1 to 42, they are: 64, 0, 64, 2112,  4160, 5184, 6208, 7232, 8256, 8768, 9280, 9792, 10304, 10816...